# Tensorflow DNNClassifier.fit error: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am trying to analyse a dataset with 60 columns (FEATURES = 59 columns (mix of both integers and floats), LABEL = columns named TARGET with 0/1 value)

I obtain the following error while trying to fit the model:

`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Following is the code used:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import urllib

import itertools

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

COLUMNS = ["DEMAdmNo","target","PEV_30","PEV_365","lhlos","LTSD","LNOSD","comorbidity_index","AdmD_3","AdmD_7","AdmD_8","AdmD_9","AdmD_11","AdmD_13","AdmD_14","AdmD_15","AdmD_16","AdmD_18","AdmD_20","AdmD_21","AdmD_22","AdmD_23","AdmD_26","AdmD_27","AdmD_28","AdmD_30","AdmD_31","AdmD_32","AdmD_33","AdmD_36","DisP_1","DisP_2","DisP_4","DisP_5","DisP_6","DisP_7","DisP_11","DisP_12","DisP_13","DisP_14","DisP_16","Disc_8","Disc_10","Disc_11","Disc_12","Disc_14","Disc_15","Disc_17","Disc_21","Disc_22","Disc_23","Disc_24","Disc_25","Disc_26","Disc_27","Disc_28","Disc_29"]

FEATURES = ["DEMAdmNo","PEV_30","PEV_365","lhlos","LTSD","LNOSD","comorbidity_index","AdmD_3","AdmD_7","AdmD_8","AdmD_9","AdmD_11","AdmD_13","AdmD_14","AdmD_15","AdmD_16","AdmD_18","AdmD_20","AdmD_21","AdmD_22","AdmD_23","AdmD_26","AdmD_27","AdmD_28","AdmD_30","AdmD_31","AdmD_32","AdmD_33","AdmD_36","DisP_1","DisP_2","DisP_4","DisP_5","DisP_6","DisP_7","DisP_11","DisP_12","DisP_13","DisP_14","DisP_16","Disc_8","Disc_10","Disc_11","Disc_12","Disc_14","Disc_15","Disc_17","Disc_21","Disc_22","Disc_23","Disc_24","Disc_25","Disc_26","Disc_27","Disc_28","Disc_29"]

LABEL = "target"

# Load datasets
training_set = pd.read_csv("Performance_train_jun5.csv", skipinitialspace=True,skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
test_set = pd.read_csv("Performance_test_jun5.csv", skipinitialspace=True,skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)

def my_input_fn(data_set):
  feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values)
                  for k in FEATURES}
  labels = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL].values)
  return feature_cols, labels

classifier = 
    tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=my_input_fn(training_set),
                                              hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                              n_classes=2,
                                              model_dir="/tmp/h_model")

      INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_evaluation_master': '', '_task_type': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_master': '', '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_model_dir': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x000000000DA51908>, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
}
, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_task_id': 0, '_environment': 'local', '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_is_chief': True}


classifier.fit(input_fn=my_input_fn(training_set), steps=2000)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I have the following questions with regard to the above code:

1) Since my FEATURES are a mix of int and float datatype.Will they cause an issue while converting them to a tensor?

2) My understanding is that the my_input_fn call in the classifier.fit should read both the features and target data. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the error: `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable` it's just a standard python error due to a wrong access to tuples. Example:

Create a tuple: `my_tuple = ('elem1','elem2')`

Access it in the **right** way:
*In[0]:* `my_tuple[0]`
*Out[0]*: `'elem1'`

Access it in a **bad** way:
*In[1]:* `my_tuple(0)` (Note parenthesis)
 
*Out[1]*: `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

So, that error is only telling you that you're trying to **access** to a **tuple value** with **parenthesis** instead of **square braquets that is the way to go.**

*QUESTIONS*

*1)* Yes, it will cause an issue if not well preprocessed. It is possible for your problem to cast the int features to float? Maybe you could try that approach.

*2)* I didn't check if the function is correct, but yes, it should do that. The things is that the function **returns a tuple** and you have to access the values in the right way (exposed above)

*Note: If you want more help, posting your csv file ('Performance_train_jun5.csv') somewhere would help a lot*

Comment: I had tried to cast the int features to float and it seems to work. I will work on the preprocessing further. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

According to Tensorflow's documentation, the parameter **'input_fn' must receive a function object (i.e., input_fn=my_input_fn)**, not the return value of a function call. This is the reason for your TypeError with the 'fit'. Check out the following link to see how to use a function with parameters for the input_fn parameter.
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn